# Why CA's baseline requirement have 22 on Authorized ports while there is no allowed way to use it?

Tags: certificate-authority

while reading [Baseline Requirement for Public CA](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.6.3.pdf) I noticed something.

1.

> Authorized Ports: One of the following ports: 80 (http), 443 (http), 25 (smtp), 22 (ssh).

this includes port 22 and implies there is some way to use SSH for something.
but in the entire documents it appears only 4 times. First on definition itself, and 
3.2.2.4.6 Agreed-Upon Change to Website (needs to be http or https)
3.2.2.4.9 Test Certificate (Must via TLS)
3.2.2.4.10. TLS Using a Random Number (Must via TLS)

As SSH is nether http/https nor use TLS, where is no way to use this port for domain validation(unless you are weirdo runs a webserver on port 22). why CAA included this port? was there a historical method that retired?

Comment: Good question. Dunno. But here's a bit of discussion about the list in 2015: https://cabforum.org/pipermail/validation/2015-August/thread.html#134 -- And here's another discussion from 2018: https://cabforum.org/pipermail/public/2018-March/thread.html#13047 -- I've got a feeling they're not too sure themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> (unless you are weirdo runs a webserver on port 22)

It sounds weird but I think that is exactly what this is about.

Ryan Sleevi of Google [had this to say](https://cabforum.org/pipermail/public/2018-March/013056.html):

```
Ryan Sleevi sleevi at google.com 
Fri Mar 2 08:51:19 MST 2018
Previous message: [cabfpub] [Ext] BR Authorized Ports, add 8443
Next message: [cabfpub] [Ext] BR Authorized Ports, add 8443
Messages sorted by: [ date ] [ thread ] [ subject ] [ author ]
On Fri, Mar 2, 2018 at 10:08 AM, Paul Hoffman via Public <
public at cabforum.org> wrote:

> On Mar 1, 2018, at 7:51 AM, Ben Wilson via Public <public at cabforum.org>
> wrote:
> >
> > Forwarding from Richard Wang:
> >
> > The current BRs say:
> >
> > Authorized Ports: One of the following ports: 80 (http), 443 (http), 25
> (smtp), 22 (ssh).
> >
> > But many internal networks use the port 8443, broadly used in Apache
> server, today, one of our customers uses this port and can't change to use
> another port, I wish you can help to add this port 8443 to be allowed in
> the BRs, thanks.
>
> It appears that the BRs currently are talking about authorizing
> *services*, not ports. That is, I would not expect to be able to put a HTTP
> server on port 22 on my system and have that considered authorized by the
> BRs.
>

That is intentionally permitted.
[...]
```